# XSLT Formatting to remove empty columns (And the headers)

Tags: xslt

I have a database field I am pulling xml out of. This field contains the content from multiple XML feeds of which I need two. I am displaying the XML on a page and using XSLT to format it.

My issue is that there could be up to 40 elements per message in the DB, of that I am looking for about 30. However, not all messages will have all 30. I need help figuring out how to remove a column if there is no data to display.

If I can use XSLT then great, if it is JavaScript(Jquery) then that is fine too. There will never be more then one row and one header at a time.

Here is a sample of the XML

```
<MessageToUser>
  <Name>Bob</Name> 
  <MessageType>Text Message</MessageType> 
  <MessageID>121223</MessageID>
  <ResponseTo />
  <Message>Call Me Please </Message> 
  <OfficePhone>555-555-1212</OfficePhone>
  <CellPhone>555-555-5555</CellPhone>
</MessageToUser>
```

And here is the XSL I am using

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .Header{min-width: 100px;background-color:#9acddd;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th class="Header">Name</th>
        <th class="Header">Message</th>
        <th class="Header">Cell Phone</th>
        <th class="Header">Office Phone</th>
        <th class="Header">Message Type</th>
        <th class="Header">Message Time</th>
        <th class="Header">Message ID</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="MessageFromUser">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Message" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="CellPhone" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="OfficePhone" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="MessageType" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="MessageTime" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="MessageID" /></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="MessageToUser">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Message" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="CellPhone" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="OfficePhone" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="MessageType" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="MessageTime" /></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="MessageID" /></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
 </body>
```

Using this XML MessageTime is blank and that column should be removed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @zk: Your goal is not clear. Do you want to "remove" a column **from the whole table** if there is no data for that column **in the whole input source**?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that is very generic and is based on a better design, using a fundamental XSLT design pattern. :)

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, if there is no data for a column then it should not be displayed. When pulled from the database, the XML will either be a "MessageToUser" or "MessageFromUser" (never both), and either can have any combination of the listed elements, but not duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:Layout>
  <html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
        .Header{min-width: 100px;background-color:#9acddd;}
      </style>
   </head>
     <body>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <header name="Name">Name</header>
            <header name="Message">Message</header>
            <header name="CellPhone">Cell Phone</header>
            <header name="OfficePhone">Office Phone</header>
            <header name="MessageType">Message Type</header>
            <header name="MessageTime">Message Time</header>
            <header name="MessageID">Message ID</header>
        </tr>
        <every select="MessageFromUser">
         <tr>
            <Name/>
            <Message/>
            <CellPhone/>
            <OfficePhone/>
            <MessageType/>
            <MessageTime/>
            <MessageID/>
         </tr>
        </every>
        <every select="MessageToUser">
         <tr>
            <Name/>
            <Message/>
            <CellPhone/>
            <OfficePhone/>
            <MessageType/>
            <MessageTime/>
            <MessageID/>
         </tr>
        </every>
       </table>
      </body>
   </html>
 </my:Layout>

 <xsl:variable name="vLayout" select="document('')/*/my:Layout/*"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:param name="pContextNode"/>
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
       <xsl:with-param name="pContextNode" select="$pContextNode"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Name|Message|CellPhone|OfficePhone|MessageType|MessageTime|MessageID">
  <xsl:param name="pContextNode"/>

  <xsl:if test="not($vDoc/*/*[not(*[name()=name(current())])])">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="$pContextNode/*[name()=name(current())]"/></td>
  </xsl:if>

 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vLayout"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="header">
  <xsl:if test="not($vDoc/*/*[not(*[name()=current()/@name])])">
    <th class="Header"><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="every">
   <xsl:variable name="vLayoutTop" select="."/>
   <xsl:for-each select="$vDoc/*/*[name()=current()/@select]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$vLayoutTop/*">
     <xsl:with-param name="pContextNode" select="."/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (the provided one and added `MessageFromUser`):

```
<Messages>
    <MessageFromUser>
        <Name>Bob</Name>
        <MessageType>Text Message</MessageType>
        <MessageID>121223</MessageID>
        <ResponseTo />
        <Message>Call Me Please </Message>
        <OfficePhone>555-555-1212</OfficePhone>
        <CellPhone>555-555-5555</CellPhone>
    </MessageFromUser>
    <MessageToUser>
        <Name>Bob</Name>
        <MessageType>Text Message</MessageType>
        <MessageID>121223</MessageID>
        <ResponseTo />
        <Message>Call Me Please </Message>
        <OfficePhone>555-555-1212</OfficePhone>
        <CellPhone>555-555-5555</CellPhone>
    </MessageToUser>
</Messages>
```

**produces the wanted output**, in which the empty column 1MessageTime` is not displayed:

```
<html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="my:my">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <style type="text/css">
        .Header{min-width: 100px;background-color:#9acddd;}
      </style></head>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th class="Header">Name</th>
            <th class="Header">Message</th>
            <th class="Header">Cell Phone</th>
            <th class="Header">Office Phone</th>
            <th class="Header">Message Type</th>
            <th class="Header">Message ID</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>Call Me Please </td>
            <td>555-555-5555</td>
            <td>555-555-1212</td>
            <td>Text Message</td>
            <td>121223</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>Call Me Please </td>
            <td>555-555-5555</td>
            <td>555-555-1212</td>
            <td>Text Message</td>
            <td>121223</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Do note**:

1. **A better design** (fill-in-the-blanks) **is used**, that separates the code and presentation. **This is one of the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design (fill-in-the blanks) pattern**.
2. **This design allows the same code to be used with different layouts** (passed as parameter) to produce completely different-looking results.
3. **The identity rule copies "as-is" all non-variable nodes of the Layout**.
4. **We override the identity rule only for the "variable" parts of the Layout**.
5. **The auxhiliary element `every` specifies that iterative processing should be performed**.
6. **In a practical application the `<my:Layout>` element will reside as a separate XML document** in a separate file and in this case one must replace `document('')/*` with `document('theFileURI')`. The greatest generality is achieved when this file URI is passed as a parameter to the XSLT transformation.
7. **The condition tested in order to process only fields/columns that appear at least once at least in one record** is (for headers):

`not($vDoc/*/*[not(*[name()=current()/@name])])`

A similar condition for cells is:

`not($vDoc/*/*[not(*[name()=name(current())])])`

Comment: When I try this, it comes back with no data. I even tried your xml and xsl on w3schools xslt test page and get no results. http://w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex1

Comment: @zk: This means you have a copy/paste error. I always test my answers before publishing them. I get the same correct results using 7 different XSLT 1.0 processors, including MSXML (3,4,6), .NET XslCompiledTransform and XslTransform, Saxon 6.5.5 and AltovaXML (XML Spy).

Comment: @zk: Other reasons for the transformation not producing results are that the `document()` function may be disabled on your host or that the transformation is loaded only from RAM (not from a file). In the latter case, put the `<my:Layout>` element as a separate XML document in a separate file and replace `document('')/*` with `document('theFileName')`

Comment: I have found one of my issues. The XML is coming from a database and the root element will either be "MessageToUser" or "MessageFromUser" so in the case of your xsl, it is failing for me. If I take the xml and put it into a file inside an element called "Messages" it works. However, as I am pulling from a DB (asp.net 2.0) and using an XML object I am not sure how to add the root element.

Comment: Ok, I have figured out how to add a new root element to the XML on the fly and I got this working now for the most part. I have a few little formatting changes now that I can see it. Thanks so much for your time and help.  zk

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

```
<xsl:if test="MessageTime">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="MessageTime" /></td>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: I tried this and it seemed to make no difference. Being new to XSL I am not sure I did it right, but I added it just like you have above.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="notEmptyAll" match="/root/MessageToUser/*" use="local-name()"/> 

<xsl:template match="root">
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    th {min-width: 100px;background-color:#9acddd;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="MessageToUser[1]/*" mode="header"/>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="MessageToUser"/>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="header">
<xsl:if test="count( key('notEmptyAll', local-name())[text()] ) != 0">
    <th>        
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    </th>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MessageToUser">
<tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="tbody"/>
</tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="tbody">
<xsl:if test="count( key('notEmptyAll', local-name())[text()] ) != 0">
    <td>        
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this XML input:

```
<root>
<MessageToUser>
    <Name>Bob</Name> 
    <MessageType>Text Message</MessageType> 
    <MessageID>121223</MessageID>
    <ResponseTo>   </ResponseTo>
    <Message>Call Me Please </Message> 
    <OfficePhone></OfficePhone>
    <CellPhone>555-555-5555</CellPhone>  
 </MessageToUser>
 <MessageToUser>
    <Name></Name> 
    <MessageType>Text Message</MessageType> 
    <MessageID>121223</MessageID>
    <ResponseTo>   </ResponseTo>
    <Message>Call Me Please </Message> 
    <OfficePhone>555-555-1212</OfficePhone>
    <CellPhone>555-555-5555</CellPhone>  
 </MessageToUser>
 </root>
```

will provide this result (excerpt):

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>MessageType</th>
        <th>MessageID</th>
        <th>Message</th>
        <th>OfficePhone</th>
        <th>CellPhone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>Text Message</td>
        <td>121223</td>
        <td>Call Me Please </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>555-555-5555</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Text Message</td>
        <td>121223</td>
        <td>Call Me Please </td>
        <td>555-555-1212</td>
        <td>555-555-5555</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thus all elements, that have at least one non-empty value, are displayed.

`local-name` can be unsufficient for you, cause headers will be like `OfficePhone`. This can be solved with substrings or with "vocabulary". Please free to comment what will suit better, cause it's not obvious from your XML excerpt.

I didn't use `MessageFromUser`, cause you didn't provide XML sample with it.